# How can I substring a JSON transform? And how work the JOLT "scopes"?

Tags: json, jolt

I'm trying to use JOLT transform but this are being a really mess, how can I convert this ipnut to this output using JSON Transform? I'm do not understanding the sintax of JOLT. When I try to substring the "client" this works, but when I do the same with the "date" this don't work....

**INPUT**

```json
{
  "client": "18f085b6-eca2-4f20-a5da-910b9043c8b3",
  "name": "clientName",
  "dateControl": {
    "date": "2020-07-16T14:08:53.708671+00:00"
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```json
{
  "client": "18f085b6-eca2-4f20-a5da-910b9043c8b3",
  "name": "clientName",
  "dateControl": {
    "date": "20200716"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should show your specification file

Answer (score 2):

You can try out below Jolt Spec.

INPUT

```json
{
  "dateTime": "2020-07-16T14:08:53.708671+00:00"
}
```

Jolt spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "dateTime": "=substring(@(1,dateTime),0,10)"
    }
  }
]
```

Output

```json
{
  "dateTime" : "2020-07-16"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can gradually apply the functions `substring` to extract the first ten characters in order to get the date portion only, then `split` by dashes so as to `join` back to get rid of them along with the **modify-overwrite-beta** spec., and then delete the auxiliary *key-value* pairs by using **remove** spec. such as

**Input**:

```json
{
  "client": "18f085b6-eca2-4f20-a5da-910b9043c8b3",
  "name": "clientName",
  "dateControl": {
    "date": "2020-07-16T14:08:53.708671+00:00"
  }
}
```

**Jolt Spec**:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "dateControl": {
        "date1": "=substring(@(1,date),0,10)",
        "date2": "=split('-',@(1,date1))",
        "date": "=join('',@(1,date2))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "dateControl": {
        "date1": "",
        "date2": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Result:

```json
{
  "client" : "18f085b6-eca2-4f20-a5da-910b9043c8b3",
  "name" : "clientName",
  "dateControl" : {
    "date" : "20200716"
  }
}
```